What is the general procedure of finding an ergodic invariant measure for an action?
I want to find an ergodic invariant measure for the action of $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
On the torus $\mathbb T^2.$
What is the general procedure of finding an ergodic invariant measure for an action?

Regarding your title question, I don't think that the general procedure exists at all, in the sense of some kind of constructive procedure that you can carry out on any problem. There is a general abstract description of the ergodic invariant measures and how they are situated inside the space of all invariant measures, using Choquet's theorem. It is not constructive.... but perhaps you can use it as a guideline.

What construction of ergodic measures did you learn from the answer to your other question?

thank you very much @LeeMosher

@MoisheKohan let me read it first and I will let you know

@MoisheKohan   is it by taking the average of Dirac measures?

Try to be more specific...

I think this is the case if we have rational rotations but incase of rational rotations things might be different. I also do not know how can I go to the torus then and what will be the support of Dirac measure in case of the torus, what are the nice subsets @MoisheKohan

This matrix is not a rotation in any sense. But can you find at least one periodic orbit?

@MoisheKohan then what?

And then use averaging on that orbit. This is what you should have learned from the answer to your other question. If you can find a fixed point, averaging will be even easier. :)

Time averaged measures are invariant measures for well-posed dynamical systems so any analytic solution should yield a measure

What do you mean by analytic solution?@whpowell96 could you please provide a solution below so that I can read it thoroughly?

To answer the title question: There is no general procedure. In many cases, describing ergodic measures for the given dynamical system is a very hard problem which takes years to solve. (Raghunathan's conjecture is one of such examples.) There are some theorems that help you to prove unique ergodicity.
But, in the case of your dynamical system, describing ergodic measures is easier.  Let $T$ denote the map of the torus $T^2$ given by your matrix.
For $y\in [0,1]$ let $L_y$ denote the line $\{(x,y): x\in \mathbb R\}\subset \mathbb R^2$ and let $C_y$ denote the projection of this line to the torus $T^2$ under the standard covering map $\mathbb R^2\to T^2$. This projection is a copy of the unit circle. Then the linear map given by your upper triangular matrix projects to the rotation $R_\alpha$ on the circle $C_y$, where the rotation angle $\alpha$ equals $2\pi y$. In particular, if $y$ is rational, $R_\alpha$ is a rotation of finite order and if $y$ is irrational, it is a rotation of infinite order. Each irrational rotation is uniquely ergodic and the unique invariant ergodic probability measure is the (normalized) Lebesgue measure on the circle (there is a good chance that whatever book on ergodic theory you are reading proves this result). If $y$ is rational, you get a rotation of finite order. Such rotations are not uniquely ergodic. Suppose that $N$ is the order of rotation. Pick an orbit $\{p_1,...,p_N\}=\{R^n_\alpha p: n=1,...,N\}$ of the cyclic group generated by such a rotation; here $p$ is any point on $S^1$. Then
$$
\mu = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \delta_{p_n}
$$
is an ergodic measure on $S^1$ with respect to $R_\alpha$. You should try to prove that all ergodic measures invariant under $R_\alpha$ are of this form. Also, try to prove ergodicity of $T$-action on $(S^1, \mu)$ using the fact that a probability measure $\mu$ on a space $X$ is ergodic under a transformation $T$ if and only if there is no $T$-invariant decomposition $X=A\sqcup B$ such that $\mu(A) \mu(B)>0$. (Such a proof is easier than the one from given to your earlier question.)
Now, all $T$-invariant ergodic probability measures $\mu$ on $T^2$ can be described as follows:
Every such measure $\mu$ is supported in one of the invariant circles $C_y\subset T^2$ and has the form described as above: It is either the (normalized) Lebesgue measure (if $y$ is irrational) or it is a measure supported on a (finite) $T$-orbit (if $y$ is rational).

@Emptymind: I do not have currently access to my library, but for unique ergodicity of irrational rotations, take a look for instance here. You normalize Lebesgue measure to make it a probability measure. Rational rotations have finite orbits. It is called a $T$-orbit because $T$ is the name of the transformation.

Can I have all this lecture notes please? When you have time can you share them with me?

@Emptymind: These are not my notes, it took me about 1 second to go one level up in the link: https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/Charles.Walkden/ergodic-theory/

What is the support in case of irrational rotations on the torus? I know that Lebesgue measures have full support

You should read few more times what I wrote; so far, you misunderstood it. $T$ does not define an irrational rotation of the torus. It defines a family of irrational rotations, one for each circle $C_y$ ($y$ is irrational). For every such invariant circle $C_y$ one has an ergodic measure $\mu_y$, whose support is $C_y$.

I see thank you very much!
